# How to push a declared function into an array and later invoke it

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

The following code works great.  It pushes 10 unnamed `functions` into an `array` and then successfully executes the 7th item in the `array`.

```js
var storeStuff = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    storeStuff.push(function() {
    console.log(i * i);
    });
}

storeStuff[6]();
```

However the test function above is tiny.  If I had a large `function` with many lines of code I'd likely want to declare it outside of the `push`.

For example what if I wanted to `push` a previously defined `function` and later invoke it like the example below?

```js
var storeStuff = [];

function externalFunction(temp) {
    console.log(temp * temp)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    storeStuff.push(externalFunction(i));
}

storeStuff[6]();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as written and everything I've tried crashed and burned.  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You may mean `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    storeStuff.push(externalFunction);
}

storeStuff[6](6);`

Comment: you can not call the function while passing

Answer (score 1):

Use function declaration as below

```
var storeStuff = [];

externalFunction = function(temp) {
    console.log(temp * temp)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    storeStuff.push(externalFunction);
}
storeStuff[6](6);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  How does `storeStuff.push(externalFunction);` know to send the `i` counter to externalFunction?  Why isn't it `storeStuff.push(externalFunction(i));`

Comment: that you should pass when calling that function. May be the index you are using. Like storeStuff[6](6); storeStuff[7](7); etc